# Typescript + React: bitwise & and Props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am having some trouble picturing what is happening in my head. If I have props that include a prop injected by a HOC, then I will get errors because I did not include that prop when calling the component (and it is not optional)

```
interface Props {
  name: string;
  HOCProp: string;
}

const Component = ({ name, HOCProp }: Props) => <div>{name}</div> 

export default HOC(Component)
```

If I call this component in another file without the HOCProp there is an error because I did not include the prop that was injected by the HOC.

```
<Component name="hello" />
```

This gives an error because the `HOCProp` is not present even though it actually is present in the component because the HOC gave it to the component.

However, if I include a bitwise `&` then it works as expected.

```
interface Props {
  name: string;
}

const Component = ({ name, HOCProp }: Props & HOCPropType) => <div>{name}</div> 

export default HOC(Component)
```

It seems more likely that the bitwise `|` would work as expected, but its not what is used. How is the typescript compiler interpreting this and seeing that it is not an error?

Comment: Why would a union work and not an intersection? The HOC component's props are of type `Props` *and* `HOCPropType`. It's not either, but both.

Comment: For more details, see here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html  But basically what @Li357 is saying is, these aren't bit-wise operators, rather they're Union and Intersection operators.  They're wholly separate from the bit-wise operators, as they operate on Types rather than bitfields.

Answer (score 0):

Intersections are perfectly valid:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Your code "adds" the types together in a union, creating a single type with the members of both `Props` and `HOCPropType`. There's no reason that would be an error.

Comment: well I certainly get an error if I call `Component` without `HOCProps` when HOCProp is defined in the interface and not with `&`

Comment: @deltaskelta Maybe I've misunderstood the question.

Comment: I updated the question to be a little bit more precise